# Django template breaking model value string at space

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I have the following HTML template in Django:

```
<select name="store" id="store_select">
    <option>Search by Store</option>
    {% for store in stores%}
    <option value= {{store.store_name}} >{{store.store_name}}</option>  
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

However, it renders the following:

```
<select name="store" id="store_select">
    <option>Search by Store</option>
    <option value= "Best" buy >Best buy</option>  
    <option value= "Costco" >Costco</option>  
    <option value= "Staples" >Staples</option>  
</select>
```

How do I make it render **"Best buy"** and not **"Best" buy** ?

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrap it in double quotes (`"…"`):

```
<option value="{{ store.store_name }}">{{ store.store_name }}</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

**using quotes:**

```
<option value="{{store.store_name}}">{{store.store_name}}</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

To make the value rendered as "Best Buy", wrap the `{{store.store_name}}` part in quotation marks:

```
<select name="store" id="store_select">
    <option>Search by Store</option>
    {% for store in stores%}
    <option value="{{store.store_name}}">{{store.store_name}}</option>  
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```